# Configuring minor grid line color/alpha in matplotlib style-sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Is there any way of configuring the minor grid lines to have a different default alpha or color value in the matplotlibrc file, or in a style sheet?

This applies to both lines:

```
grid.color : black
grid.alpha : 0.5
```

And I would like to not have to do this in my Python script every time. So how do i apply this:

```
grid(b=True, which='minor', color='r', linestyle='--')
```

to the default matplotlibrc, or a style sheet.

Comment: It's not possible.